# Unity3D: Top and bottom portions of sphere are collapsing when a 360 image is set as its texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, 360-panorama

I just learnt to put 360 photos on the inside of a sphere from [here](http://theta360.guide/blog/video,/unity/2016/10/16/video-file-on-unity-sphere.html), but when I put any 360 photo, the top and bottom portions look like they are compressed, stitched and nailed on the poles :\

[image]

EDIT: Tried adding Cull Front to this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37123903/3125070) from an SO answer, but still I'm getting something like this

[image]

**Is this the reason?**

They seem to me as if only 720 or 1080 vertical pixels swept 360 degrees horizontally while missing the top and bottom portions (giving cylindrical and not spherical image). I just feel like a single pixel sweeping 360 degrees (when rotating along y-axis) would give a 1 pixel line, while this horizontal flat circle needs to sweep along x-axis to create a whole sphere. *Correct me if I'm wrong*

**How do I apply a 360 panoramic [picture](http://www.virtualtoursgta.com/images/portfolio/panoramas/11.jpg) to the inside of the sphere so that it looks like a complete virtual env?** Or maybe I can't?

Comment: Maybe there sphere needs more details...Fire up Maya or any external 3D software, create a sphere with high subdivisions(60) then import it into Unity. See if the problem is still there.

Comment: I tried with 64 segments and 64 rings and it looks completely pixelated. Btw, just simply assume you're connecting the top portion of this [image](http://www.virtualtoursgta.com/images/portfolio/panoramas/11.jpg) it would just result in the screenshots I posted above; just have a feeling that even if the shader and object are perfect, stitching the top and bottom would result in those warps

Comment: I just checked a few 360 posts in fb to see how that looks at the top and the bottom, and I just found that I'm not able to look at the top and the bottom, it;s more like a cylinder's surface area, I **can't** look above and below 50 degrees from the midline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image I chose was not **equirectangular**

I got more information and guidelines [here](https://medium.com/@verochan/how-to-make-a-360%C2%BA-image-viewer-with-unity3d-b1aa9f99cabb)

> Prepare a suitable image The image to be used in the viewer
>   must have a 2:1 aspect ratio and equirectangular projection, this
>   means the top and bottom part of the image have to be stretched in
>   order to render correctly inside the sphere

Solution:

- Make sure you use an equirectangular image [top and bottom parts will be stretched]
- Make a sphere and use an equirectangular shader [either invert the normals of the sphere or add `Cull Front` in the shader]
- When the image is textured on the sphere, the progressive (literal pixel) compression towards the top and bottom of the sphere compensates the progressive stretching towards the top and bottom present in an equirectangular image

Comment: Hi, can you please share the shader you used to solve the issue? Thanks in advance :)