# Unity Shader For 360 Virtual Tour

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, shader, coordinates, virtual-tour

Currently im creating a virtual tour by wrapping a material of a panorama image onto a sphere and turning it inside out. To do that, i used a shader that i got from another stack overflow, the problem is there's no explanation on how to understand the code and i really need to understand the algorithm on how to turn the material inside out... all i know so far is that its using an algorithm  to convert normal coordinates to pole coordinate but i still cant find an example to learn from it.. can anyone tell me how this algorithm works? or how to learn this algorithm and any references? Thank you!

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088286/360-viewer-in-unity-texture-appears-warped-in-the-top-and-bottom)

Here are the shader code :

```
Shader "Custom/Equirectangular" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Diffuse (RGB) Alpha (A)", 2D) = "gray" {}
    }

    SubShader{
        Pass {
            Tags {"LightMode" = "Always"}
            Cull Front

            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #pragma glsl
                #pragma target 3.0

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata {
                   float4 vertex : POSITION;
                   float3 normal : NORMAL;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4    pos : SV_POSITION;
                    float3    normal : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert (appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.normal = v.normal;
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _MainTex;

                #define PI 3.141592653589793

                inline float2 RadialCoords(float3 a_coords)
                {
                    float3 a_coords_n = normalize(a_coords);
                    float lon = atan2(a_coords_n.z, a_coords_n.x);
                    float lat = acos(a_coords_n.y);
                    float2 sphereCoords = float2(lon, lat) * (1.0 / PI);
                    return float2(1 - (sphereCoords.x * 0.5 + 0.5), 1 - sphereCoords.y);
                }

                float4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
                {
                    float2 equiUV = RadialCoords(IN.normal);
                    return tex2D(_MainTex, equiUV);
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "VertexLit"
```

I have tried searching about converting normal coordinates to spherical coordinate but the formula is different from the shader.

Comment: I found what i was looking for, it is called equirectangular projection.